# Symbol Not Found in Xcode when clicking a type like UIWindow, and no code hint anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I don't know what happened.

The code works perfectly, but the Xcode do not prompt the code hint any more.

When you cmd + left click a type like UITableView, 'Symbol Not Found'

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens sometimes because of corrupted delivered data. Go to `Xcode->Preferences->Locations`, then click on the little arrow to locate the folder of "Delivered data" in Finder. Delete all contents in that folder, then restart Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this issue is really annoying, it works perfect, thank you again.